# Replace double backslashes with single backslash

Tags: c#

I have created a search function within a media player that uses a list-box to output the data and when a user clicks a song I want that song to play. However, when I select a song for some reason I get two black slashes instead of one. Please help. I've tried replacing them already.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Username\Music\";
        path = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\"); 
        string selectedsong, filetoplay;

        selectedsong = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        filetoplay = path + selectedsong + ".mp3";

        Form1.wplayer.URL = filetoplay;
```

What I'm currently getting at the moment is C:\\Users\\Username\\Music\\Song.mp3 and as a result the song won't play

[image: The file paths after I click in the listbox]

Comment: I bet you don't really have double backslashes. What you're actually seeing is the representation of `\ ` in the debugger, which is `\\ `. What happens when you click magnifying glass next to the item you're observing in the debugger?

Comment: When you are creating "path" use "Path.Combine" method. I posted answare. Don't forget to mark as "solution".

Comment: Still shows the double backslash.

Comment: In debugger, or in exception?

Comment: Does the path `C:\Users\Username\Music` definitely exist?

Comment: And what is the exception, that cause, the music don't want to play?

Comment: I don't have a Username directory that directory is fake for the sake of this post but it still has the double backslash. There isn't an exception at all it just won't play the music because it can't find any due to the double backslash.

Comment: Your problem can be name of song. Did you try song with no "space" in it's name?

Comment: It's not the song I've checked the names of them and they're correct. It's definitely the double backslash that's causing the issue.

Comment: You are sure, that: A) You test your solution, with 1 world song title, and B) you are sure, that this file is in that directory on your disk? and C) you are sure, that application does not throw any exceptions?

Comment: It's ***definitely not*** the double backslash that is causing the issue, because your strings don't have double backslashes. You're reading the debugger incorrectly and it's leading you to an incorrect conclusion. Really.

Comment: I'm positive it isn't the file name of the song since I've tried it with single word songs and I wouldn't be able to select a song that isn't on my disk since the list box loads from a folder of songs. Yes the application doesn't throw any exceptions it's all due to the backslashes.

Comment: This might help: http://screencast.com/t/WLdP4SVT
Click the magnifying glass and choose text visualizer and that'll show you the value of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `Replace` in your code is doing nothing because there are no double backslashes in your string... As others have already pointed out, it's just a matter of debugger visualization so you can copy that and use it in your code, for example.

So, if you do this:

[image: code]

You see the double backslash there but it's not in the actual string, of course. See what you get in the console:

[image: Console output]

My advice is that you simulate a double click on the selected file by running this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filetoplay);
```

It should open your default mp3 player. I think it will give you an error due to missing file, wrong format or something. If it plays, then the bug is on the player part of your code and you can stop worrying about the double slashes. :)

Comment: Could you find the cause of the problem?

Comment: Not yet, but It did indeed play using the windows media player. I'm a student learning C# so all of this is a big learning curve. I'll figure it out thanks for comment.

Comment: It works now !!! Awesome. The double dashes really doesn't matter was over complicating it.

Comment: So what was the problem then? ;)

Comment: Well it's silly really. My list box was reading in the actual title name attributes of the song's so it look's nice and pretty because actual file names are ugly and was trying to find that file name when in fact it didn't exist. Your process start code gave me the idea to change around the reading in process. Thank you very much.

Comment: So you were trying to open a file based on the ID3 title actually... Now I see that's why you were adding the ".mp3"! Had you used the real file name, there would have been no reason for it to miss its extension unless you had deliberately removed it beforehand. I'm glad it's working now. :)

Answer (score 1):

It shows two backslashes in the variable value because the ­\ is escaped. If you print the variable value to console, you should find that it has only one backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Path.Combine

[link to msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

P.S. Single \ is "escape sign" and is used with "special charakters" ex: "\t" is "tab" and "\n" is "new line", that means, when you want to post "\" in your string, you must post "\". 
P.S.2 When you are creating "path" use "Patch.Combine".